# Show Dynamic Text on a Paper using Vuforia augmented for iOS and android

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have a requirement to show a text on a paper when mobile device place it on the paper  ,this is basically an augmented reality feature.

There will be an maker in the paper , and the app it self will recognise the marker and should place a dynamic text which receives from server . So this text will change

So as a start i decided to move with Vuforia SDK since it has more support than any other sdks available. So i managed to run there sample apps and show there "tea pot" in my own marker ,

But now comes the hardest part , that i need to render text on the marker instead of tea pot. so seems i have two options

1) Using unity create the  2d text object 
2) Using openGL  render text as in teapot

So my question is what is the appropriate way to do this ?? i know OpenGL is not easy to implement , even the Unity will provide multiple unnecessary files both have pros and cons

what is the  best way to this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after reading few articles i managed to put a GuiLabel on top of real world object. It was all about using WorldToScreenPoint and set it to the position

```
Camera cam=Camera.current;
GUIStyle textStyle = new GUIStyle ();
textStyle.fontSize = 40;
textStyle.normal.textColor = Color.yellow;

Vector3 pos=cam.WorldToScreenPoint(targetPosition);
GUI.Label(new Rect(pos.x-40,Screen.height-pos.y,250,200),"Product Price",textStyle);
```

Comment: Using the legacy GUI is not recommended for performance reason. Also, it is not the most flexible thing to use as you need to run to see while the new UI system allows to see in Scene/game view.

Comment: what do u mean by this  ?? "as you need to run to see while the new UI system allows to see in Scene/game view." and in my sample i dont  have a Scene  / Gameview now

Comment: @user4204805 did this few years back

Answer (score 5):

You get your text from server, let's say json file. Parse it and apply the result to a text mesh object or a Text object in a world canvas.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextMesh.html

https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-text

You can place those object in place of the tea pot under the image target or modify the DefaultTrackableEventHandler so that instead of affecting Collider and Renderer on child object it would do action on any object.

Look for the OnTrackingFound/Lost methods.

Comment: thanks for the reply . i shall look in to this and will accept the answer one i manage to make it . also  what about having many  classes with unity , is that normal ?

Comment: Many classes? Kinda yes. Hundreds is quite normal for a project. Depends what you mean.

Comment: i think my requirements is pretty clear , track the image and render text  on top of it , i think only the image target will be enough for my need

Comment: Well yes. In this you can either place items instead of tea pot without changing anything if you use text mesh. If you use canvas then you'd have to change a bit since there is no renderer. So you'd have to activate/deactivate the object.

Comment: but can i use a text mash as child to the imagetarget ?

Comment: TextMesh is just a component creating a mesh out of a string. So it is basic mesh just like the teapot (it may have some special optimization process but it is irrelevant for now).

Comment: I have gone with unity samples and now  seems more familiar with  functions ,I found the OnTrackingFound() function in DefaultTrackableEventHandler and its clear i need to render my text in here , So my question  is how can i use textmesh here  ???

Comment: used following link , but it shows the  button not on top of image target https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/faq/unity-how-can-i-popup-gui-button-when-target-detected

Comment: You need to set it as world canvas and assign the camera. This makes your UI item an object in the world instead of screen object.

Comment: Well i  created a gameobject , and managed to add textmesh  so now it shows in the marker , but its shows as a 3D object , but i need to show it a normal text  not in 3d view . but if add a uitext , it doesnt  shows in the marker it just  shows in the scree

Comment: I'm a be honest, i dont understand. 3d ui is not ok but screen ui is not either.

Comment: sorry ill convert this to more technical way , TextMash shows as in 3d way , which is true , but in my requirement i dont need 3d view , 1d or 2d would be enough , as in ui-text as in here https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-text can i put ui-text on top of marker  like TextMash, probably now its clear  thanks

Comment: Ok this is the part I don't get, the marker is in the 3D space, at least camera feed representing a 3D space, and you want a screen space item to show on top of it. I'm not quite sure but maybe you want to convert the marker position to screen position and show the ui there.https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html maybe with this.

Comment: I think this is what ia have to do . And update its position when marker is moving anyway   ill try to .do this . Will put a comment on status . And ill accept this as answer .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138180/discussion-between-mr-g-and-everts).

Comment: can you guys shed some light how to do it on android native?